# basic mod_rewrite question

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to write a rule which says

xyz.com/hotels_in_someplace will direct to xyz.com/test.php?place=someplace

by using the following in my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^hotels_in_([a-z]+)$ test.php?place=$1 [L]
```

but its not working and I cant figure out why, I am running a wamp server as a dev. when i tried to run xyz.com/test.php?place=someplace (without the htaccess in the directory) it works but I suspect there's something my rule which is wrong.

additional:
whoops....my dumb ass mistake, mod_rewrite wasnt enabled...

Comment: How exactly is it not working?

Comment: Do you really have "RewriteEngine On RewriteBase /" all on one line?

Comment: I've tested this on my server and it works properly.

Comment: Did you try a simpler rule like `RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/ [L,R]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I didn't notice the RewriteBase in the question before so my point about the leading slash is null. However the RewriteRule does work on my machine.

---

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^hotels_in_([a-z]+)$ /test.php?place=$1 [L]
```

The path to test.php needs the leading slash. The way you are doing the rewrite you will be redirected to xyz.com/path/to/web/docs/on/machine/test.php and thats not what you want. :)

Also if you are you including a trailing slash in your test.

The above rule will not match `xyz.com/hotels_in_someplace/`.

To match the leading slash this should work:

```
RewriteRule ^hotels_in_([a-z]+)/?$ /test.php?place=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it without the end-line anchor ($)

```
RewriteRule ^/hotels_in_([a-z]+) /test.php?place=$1 [L]
```

Also, did you allow the .htaccess files to be parsed?

Answer (score 0):

Your example works fine for me. Might want to make a few little adjustments (see my example, which captures uppercase letters, hyphens and underscores (for hotels in countries with more than one word (united-states, united_states)) and a trailing forward slash).

```
RewriteRule ^hotels_in_([A-Za-z_-]*)(/?)$ /test.php?place=$1
```

Hope that helps.